# How to return Model in Many to Many Polymorphic Associations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations

I am able to successfully create the relationships, but I now want to identify what the model used in the relationship is, but I don't know how to access it. Could someone point me in the right direction? I have tried the following down below in the index.blade.php file, but it just returns *NULL*

1 Possible solution is to check to see if the value is empty on each relationship definition each time, but is there a laravel built in way to check?

```
@if ($event->services->isNotEmpty())
  There are services!
@endif
```

Basically I have two relationships defined courses and services. I want to check which 1 each event is.

I have the following relationships:

```
services
courses
events
schedulables
event_user
```

Events.php model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Course', 'schedulable');
    }

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Service', 'schedulable');
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Start</th>
                                <th scope="col">End</th>
                                <th scope="col">Assigned</th>
                                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                                <th scope="col">Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($events as $event)
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{$event->start_date}}</th>
                                <td>{{$event->end_date}}</td>
                                <td>{{$event->user->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::getMorphedModel($event->getMorphClass())}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{route('events.destroy', $event)}}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types), this piece of code only apply to a $service or $course model:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::getMorphedModel($event->getMorphClass())
```

You can simply define a type custom attribute inside the Event model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class Event
{
    public function getTypeAttribute()
    {
        return class_basename($this->schedulable_type);
    }
}
```

Then within the blade file, you can simply say:

```php
<td>{{$event->type}}</td>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this answer it has helped me get closer to what I am trying to achieve. When I apply this solution $event->type doesn't output anything. When I run class_basename($event) it return events when i run class_basename($event->schedulable_type) it doesn't return anything as well. Just to be clear I applied the solutino provided in the model like you showed above. My goal is to determine what the many to many polymorphic event class.